# "One time setup" screen pop ups constantly on BlueStacks

Tags: bluestacks

I can't use any app in BlueStacks since it constantly sends the "One time setup" message.

The "Disable" and "Force stop" buttons don't work for "App sync" and "BS services". No matter how many times I do it, they can't be disabled.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have "One time setup" issue too, but a bit differently from yours:

After restart "One time setup" appears and I should re-login into my BlueStack account (with Google authentication). But after that it works well.

Are you logged in a BlueStack account? I think you have to use on infree mode.

Comment: I don't have any bluestacks account and I don't want to have any. Do you think I should get a rooted version of it???